# apache2 /var/www/html 403 error

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

in `/var/www/html` i create a new folder call `ss`  when i type `ip/ss` i got following error:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /ss/ on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at 45.32.113.186 Port 80

i am using `ubuntu 16.4` version

and i tried this commands also still 403 error but i can create a folder in var/www directory

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www
```

and this my ss.conf this code save as ss.conf and upload  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled  here

```
Alias /ss/ /home/rider/serverfiles/screenshots/
<directory /home/rider/serverfiles/screenshots>
    options +Indexes
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

for apache 2.4.